# Print content and several attributes of a numpy array to a text file

Tags: python, numpy, text

I have an array. My task is to print out the array, along with its shape, size, item size, dimensions, and data type name. The output should be a text file - each attribute should be on a new line.

When I attempt to use the following code, I get the error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-76-f4d4f45285be>", line 1, in <module>
    print(a.shape)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

I have tried two options, open a text file and `np.savetxt`. Neither seems to work.

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(15).reshape(3,5)

a = print(a)

shape = print(a.shape)

size = print(a.size)

itemsize = print(a.itemsize)

ndim = print(a.ndim)

dtype = print(type(a.dtype))

with open("demo_numpy.tx","w") as text:
    text.write(a,shape,size,itemsize,ndim,dtype, file = text)

np.savetxt('demo_numpy.txt',[a,shape,size,itemsize,ndim,dtype])
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix my output?

Comment: Any particular reason why you're doing `a = print(a)`? `print` returns `None`.

Comment: I added the "variable =" so that I could list the print statements in the output file statement

Comment: Ah, you're mistaken about what print does. MSeifert explains why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` just prints the value passed in to `stdout` **and** returns `None`. If you want to access a property just do it without `print`:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(15).reshape(3,5)
shape = a.shape
size = a.size
itemsize = a.itemsize
ndim = a.ndim
dtype = a.dtype
```

And if you want to `print` don't assign the return value of `print`:

```
print(a)
print(a.shape)
print(a.size)
print(a.itemsize)
print(a.ndim)
print(a.dtype)
```

---

Note that you don't correctly write to files, in the first case you can only write one argument at a time, you need to either `str.join` them or do multiple `text.write`s. In the second case you should check the documentation of [`numpy.savetxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) - it expects an array as second argument not a list of several attributes.

For example:

```
with open("demo_numpy.tx","w") as text:
    text.write(str(a))
    text.write(str(shape))
    text.write(str(size))
    text.write(str(itemsize))
    text.write(str(ndim))
    text.write(str(dtype))

# or:
#   text.write('\n'.join(map(str, [a,shape,size,itemsize,ndim,dtype])))

np.savetxt('demo_numpy.txt', a)
```

Comment: When I try your suggestion I get two errors. One with each text function. TypeError: write() takes no keyword arguments and TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('object') and format specifier ('%.18e')

Comment: The last paragraph should explain why that happens. You're using `file.write` and `np.savetxt` incorrectly. I.e. try `np.savetxt('demo_numpy.txt', a)` instead.

Comment: Ok, so I want to access the values as per the first code block in your comment. But now, how do I print them out to a txt file with each variable on a new line?

Comment: Well, just `text.write` them one at a time and insert newlines when appropriate. :)

Comment: @MSeifert- just for clarification. I need to print the data type name, and not the datatype. Have I done this correctly? What is the difference?

Comment: The `str(a.dtype)` should be the data type name.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to use something like this:

```
# import numpy as np
# my_array = np.arange(3)
metadata = [(method, getattr(my_array, method)) for method in dir(my_array) if (not callable(getattr(my_array, method))) and (not method.startswith('__'))]
names, values = zip(*metadata)  # 2 lists
```

Then loop over `names` & `values` and write into a file.